# Create column in dataframe with TRUE if enough occurences of an id within a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with id column, col1, col2. The id can appear several times.

```
id     col1    col2
1       a       b
1       c       d
2       e       f
3       g       h
4       x       y
4       x       z
4       a       z
```

I want to create a new column with:

- TRUE if id appears at least n times (n=2) in id column
- FALSE otherwise

and to have a df like below

```
id     col1    col2   enough_id
1       a       b        True
1       c       d        True
2       e       f        False
3       g       h        False
4       x       y        True
4       x       z        True
4       a       z        True
```

I have tried this

```
df['enough_id'] = np.where(df['id'].value_counts() > 2, True, False)
```

but I got : "Length of values does not match length of index". So I guess it is because I am creating a series with df['id'].value_counts() > 2...

How could I do to get this column ? It sounds simple but I can't find. Thanks

Comment: Welcome I suggest looking at groupby and then merge later. Might not be the most efficient but will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. We can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), `ge` functions of Pandas.

```
df['enough_id'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('count').ge(2)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
   id col1 col2  enough_id
0   1    a    b       True
1   1    c    d       True
2   2    e    f      False
3   3    g    h      False
4   4    x    y       True
5   4    x    z       True
6   4    a    z       True
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion ! It has worked.I did not know this function. Very powerful. Thank you a lot ! I will use it very often !!

Comment: @get_funstuck, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning.